# Converting an Item inside a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a "master list" of all the items that exist. Then, I have a class (called Inventory) that is in charge of keeping track how many items are there, the amount could be any whole number.

My DataGrid is binding to the master list, then a specific column is in charge of displaying the amount of items in the inventory. The Inventory class is a IValueConverter.

My idea is to convert the Item from the DataGrid to an int (amount of items I have) with the Inventory class.

XAML:

```
<UserControl>

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <converters:Inventory x:Key="FindQuantity"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>

              
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding MasterList}"> <!-- Binding to the master List -->
        <DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Quantity">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

                    <DataTemplate>
                        <!-- Converting: -->
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource FindQuantity}}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>

                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</UserControl>
```

Part of the Inventory script:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
  var item = (Item)value; //<------------Here's where the Debug points the error
  return HowMany(item);
}

public int HowMany(Item item)
{
  if (storage.ContainsKey(item))
    return storage[item];
  else return 0;
}
```

Error I'm getting:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to type 'Playfield2_WPF.Objetos.Item'.'

I'm new to WPF so I don't fully understand binding. Where's my error? Did I got something wrong with the way bindings work or the problem is somewhere else? Thanks.

**Edit:**
Here's the code for the "MasterList" (It's a list of ObservableObject, a class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged. Source code: https://pastebin.com/wZiis6rF)

```
public class Inventary : ObservableObject, IValueConverter
{       
  private List<Item> _masterList;
  public List<Item> MasterList
    {
        get { return _masterList; }
        set
        {
          //this method is from the ObservableObjet class
          //It basically calls PropertyChanged from the INotifyPropertyChanged interface
            OnPropertyChanged(ref _masterList, value, nameof(MasterList)); 
        }
    }

}
   //Item is basically some int and string propierties
    public class Item : ObservableObject 
    {
        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                OnPropertyChanged(ref _name, value, nameof(Name));
            }
        }

        private decimal _cost;
        public decimal Cost
        {
            get { return _cost; }
            set
            {
                OnPropertyChanged(ref _cost, value, nameof(Cost));
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is `MasterList`? Can you please provide code for it?

Comment: @thatguy sure, just added it. It's a simple list. Is using lists a problem in WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is two example of a converter

One : Binding to other element control

```
<RadioButton  IsChecked="False" x:Name="targetradiobutton"/>
<!-- Below is a textbox that will show/hide depends on radiobutton's isChecked state!-->
<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName="targetradiobutton", Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

Two : Binding to backend variable

In test.xaml.cs

```
Public Test(){ this.DataContext = this;} //one of a way to bind to backend class. there's other way too
Public bool IsVisible{ get; set;}
```

In test.xaml

```
<!--Converting backned boolean to visibility.
<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

Converter Sample:

```
public class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is bool)
            {
                return ((bool)value) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

In your case, as you are using default binding, you are binding Textbox's Text to the converter. So you can based on the example above and bind to variable/other element that contain the target Item you want.

```
  <!-- Converting: -->
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding TargetItem, Converter={StaticResource FindQuantity}}"/>
```

Comment: So when binding an element, the Target's propriety that it binds to, is dependent on the element?... I thought it binded to the Target as a whole, and that you had to specify the exact propriety you wanted to see. That was my reasoning to just leaving Binding without a Path when converting